# Dual Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, windows-10

How do I do this, should I follow the same method as for Windows 7?
I did not try anything but am looking for suggestions.
No I don't want to use VB.
Please help.
My hard drive has around 50GB free and it's really old but the rest of my PC is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to install it as usual.

You can create a bootable USB stick by using [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) tool.
After everything is ready, **restart**(or turn off fast startup) your computer. This is because your data might lost if you resize the partition or install Ubuntu in the partition which Windows is using.

After this, you can turn on your computer(you have to change the boot order) and be welcomed to a purple screen.

Comment: I already have Windows 10, thats the ONLY OS I am currently using. I WANT to INSTALL Ubuntu ALONGSIDE it. Please help.

Comment: @AnshNanda See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the both things installed? (Ubuntu and Windows 10)?
If you do, you must have the younger OS installed first so, if you are using Ubuntu 14.04/.10 you have to install Windows 10 after it.
Its kinda complicated but if the GRUB menu doesnt appear after installing Ubuntu or Windows 10, look up on Google how to fix grub menu not appearing with ubuntu

Comment: I only have Windows 10 currently. I want to install Ubuntu with it too.